# $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{2-4z^2}\,dz\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How do you evaluate this integral? I have tried to start this, but I have not seen an integral like this in forever. Please help me out!

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{2-4z^2}\,dz\,dy$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $\int_0^2 f(z) dy=f(z) \int_0^2 dy=2f(z)$

Comment: Hint: Try the substitution $u = \sqrt{2}\sin z$ for the inside integral

Comment: There is the slight problem that the integrand is not defined on the region specified. Are there any typos?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^2 \sqrt{2-4 z^2} \, dy=2 \sqrt{2-4 z^2}$$
$$\int 2 \sqrt{2-4 z^2}\,dz=z \sqrt{2-4 z^2}+\arcsin\left(\sqrt{2} z\right)+C$$
when plugging $z=2$ we get $\arcsin(2\sqrt 2)$ which is not a real number

Anyway the result is
$$\int_0^2 2 \sqrt{2-4 z^2} \, dz=\arcsin\left(2 \sqrt{2}\right)+2 i \sqrt{14}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^2\int_0^2\sqrt{2-4z^2}dzdy=\sqrt{2}\int_0^2\int_0^2\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{2}z)^2}dzdy=\sqrt{2}i\int_0^2\int_0^2\sqrt{(\sqrt{2}z)^2-1}dzdy$$
now we know that $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1\Rightarrow \cosh^2x-1=\sinh^2x$. So we can make the substitution: $\sqrt{2}z=\cosh x\Rightarrow dz=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\sinh xdx$ which transforms our integral into:
$$I=i\int_0^2\int_{\cosh^{-1}(0)}^{\cosh^{-1}(2\sqrt{2})}\sinh^2(x)dxdy=i\left[y\right]_{y=0}^2\left[\frac{\sinh(2x)-2x}{4}\right]_{x=\cosh^{-1}(0)}^{\cosh^{-1}(2\sqrt{2})}$$

Now the only hard part left is working out a value for this second part of the answer.